# Changing chapter format in report

Tags: formatting, chapters

I'd like to change chapter format, including lines up and down and text right aligned, like in the next figure, without using `titlesec` package:

[image]

Here it's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{0\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \huge\bfseries
    % \@chapapp\space % removed
    \thechapter
    \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 25\p@
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

In the preamble, the code it's in order to change chapter format from "Chapter 1 \\ Chapter title" to "1. Chapter title".

Someone has any idea to include lines and align text to the right as shown in the above image?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `titlesec`?

Comment: Because in my main document I have a lot of packages included, and when I load `titlesec`package, compilation fails. It seems like there are problems among packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\hrule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{0\p@}
\hrule\  \\
{\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \huge\bfseries
    % \@chapapp\space % removed
    \thechapter
    \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
    \hrule
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\rule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{0\p@}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\
{\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \huge
    % \@chapapp\space % removed
    \thechapter
    \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalfont % \Huge % replaced
    \ #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 0\p@
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `\rule` it's perfect, but with `\hrule`there is no space between the bottom line and the next text line. Any fix to this?

Comment: Add  again `\vskip 20\p@` after last `\hrule`.